# What does module:disable actually do?

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, magento2.3.1

Background:

I seem to be having trouble disabling modules on my M2 2.3.1 store. Example: I had installed the CommerceBug development module but wanted to test my site without it so I ran `module:disable Company_Commercebug`.

Magento reported that the module was disabled. (I then ran the usual `setup:upgrade`, deleted all cache/generated/static directories and cleared all redis caches), but I found that the module was still outputting its CSS and JS files via the frontend.

This behaviour only stopped when I uninstalled the module using `module:uninstall`.

There is a good explanation of what `module:uninstall` does in the [Magento Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html) but there is not an equivalent explanation for `module:disable`.

So what does `module:disable` actually do? Is it meant to prevent CSS/JS/etc. from being included? How does it differ from "Disable module output" in the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `php bin/magento module:disable Company_Commercebug`, It will disable the module in `app/etc/config.php`

```
<?php
return [
  ...
    'Company_Commercebug' => 0,
  ...
    ]
];
```

So once your extension will be disabled, you need to remove it's statis using below process:

Remove following :

```
pub/static - Do not delete .htaccess
var/cache
var/composer_home
var/page_cache
var/view_preprocessed
generation/
```

Now run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` using -f if you are in developer mode.

Alternativally, you can also use below command, it will create it's static content:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Company_Commercebug --clear-static-content
```